# Winding number as topological invariant in Su-Schrieffer-Heeger (SSH) model

Tags: topological-insulators, invariants

I'm studying the SSH model, here's the [reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02295). I don't get what the definition of a topological invariant is in this case. I think the important property is that the winding number cannot be changed without either breaking a symmetry of the system or closing the bulk band gap, but why do we call it a *topological* invariant?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/reso/025/06/0765-0786) help?

Comment: It does! It still seems more of an analogy though, not really a full explanation, or am I missing something?

Comment: It's called a topological invariant because the winding number of a _continuous_ function is indeed a topological invariant, a concept defined in the branch of mathematics called algebraic topology.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent, the time-reversal symmetry and the inversion symmetry protect the topological phase. This phenomenon is called symmetry protected topological phases--SPT. So when winding number is equal to 1(0), it is a topological(trivial) phase. The two regimes can not be smoothly connected by continuously deforming the mapping without closing the gap.